# How to we skip error with SQLBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I am using SQLBulkCopy to upload bulk data into Sql Table.. the table contains the column ID as Identity column. so it will not allow dulicate record as you know..

Consoder that I have 10 rows to insert by SQLBulkCopy, among that 10 records we have 2 dulicate rows...

My questions is: Is there any way to skip that duplicate rows while inserting rows using SQLBulkCopy?

Comment: Not easily See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004525/sqlbulkcopy-error-handling-continue-on-error

Comment: Have closed as duplicate. Please reopen if this does not solve your problem and specify what you have already done to solve it. This should include a reason why the linked duplicate is not duplicate. Using this site requires doing research *before* you ask.

Comment: Staging tables are your freinds.